# ANTLR Make specific token or rule case insensitive

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm looking for a way to make certain specific Tokens case-insensitive in my ANLTR parser.
What I already tried:

1. Converting my input to all lowercase. This didn't work, for some
   parts of my grammar require case sensitivity.
2. Saving the uppercase and lowercase version of the tokens. This didn't work either cause this way my lexer file became too large (breaking the 64k limit of ANTLR).

What I hope exists is some regex trick or maybe an ANTLR flag that tells the parser to treat certain tokens differently.

---

An example:

```
SENSITIVETOKEN
:
    'footoken' 
;

INSENSITIVETOKEN
:
    'bootoken'  (some magic here)
;
```

The lexer **should** recognize `"BOOTOKEN"` as a `INSENSITIVETOKEN` 
but **not** `"FOOTOKEN"` as `SENSITIVETOKEN`

---

Thanks for your help! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution could be to declare one-letter fragments and construct tokens based on those fragments.

Example:

```
INSENSITIVETOKEN
:
    B O O T O K E N
;

fragment B: ('B'|'b');
fragment O: ('O'|'o');
fragment T: ('T'|'t');
fragment K: ('K'|'k');
fragment E: ('E'|'e');
fragment N: ('N'|'n');
```

Or, if there're not many case-insensitive tokens, simply:

```
INSENSITIVETOKEN
:
    ('B'|'b')('O'|'o')('O'|'o')('T'|'t')('O'|'o')('K'|'k')('E'|'e')('N'|'n')
;
```

Comment: Note: you can make this even shorter, e.g. `fragment B: [bB];`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But my grammar file right now is around 4700 lines. I don't think I'll be able to change this all by hand.

Comment: @JakobSachs, since these case-insensitive rules are part of the grammar, you have to change the grammar in order to get the result you want. I do not think there's any other solution to accomplish it.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Okay thanks. Guess I'll try to write a script that changes it automatically.